# Strategies for signing sections of a chef recipe file to prevent tampering

Tags: cryptography, code-signing, chef-infra

I'm looking for suggestions from the community on the best way to approach this problem:

1. I have a collection of chef recipes in git, defining labs e.g. a jenkins CI setup, which people will be able to fork and tailor to their own use
2. However, I can forsee circumstances when someone may want to add certain immutable sections of the cookbook, e.g. firewall settings
3. What strategy would make sense to lock certain sections of the file to validate that it hasn't been changed, while allowing arbitrary changes outside that
4. Ideally it would also solve the ability to obfuscate the sections if needed

Would I be adding my own DSL into the code - with a checksum for each protected block - pre-process it to unwrap and validate it before passing it to chef?

e.g. My first attempt at a format - still doesn't solve the problem of people just deleting all the signed sections - unless every file has to be signed

```
#---SIGNED-FILE SHA-256 507e74380188c07bad2fa66acb8cbbeeb63f84fcee5fd639499575654239cd49

#
# Cookbook Name:: jenkins
# Recipe:: default
#

# https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu
# This is super-simple, compared to the other Chef cookbook I found
# for Jenkins (https://github.com/fnichol/chef-jenkins).
#
# This doesn't include Chef libraries for adding Jenkin's jobs via
# the command line, but it does get Jenkins up and running.

include_recipe "apt"
include_recipe "java"

#---SIGNED-SECTION-START SHA-256 e4d3d02f14ee2a6d815a91307c610c3e182979ce8fca92cef05e53ea9c90f5c7
apt_repository "jenkins" do
  uri "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian"
  key "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key"
  components ["binary/"]
  action :add
end
#---SIGNED-SECTION-END

#---OBFUSCATED-SECTION-START SHA-256 5f536f2137dc7e2c5817de861d1329ead72b1e9d2dbb9dbe181ec7bc274dddeb
YXB0X3JlcG9zaXRvcnkgImplbmtpbnMiIGRvCiAgdXJpICJodHRwOi8vcGtnLmplbmtpbnMtY2kub3JnL2RlYmlhbiIKICBrZXkgImh0dHA6Ly9wa2cuamVua2lucy1jaS5vcmcvZGViaWFuL2plbmtpbnMtY2kub3JnLmtleSIKICBjb21wb25lbnRzIFsiYmluYXJ5LyJdCiAgYWN0aW9uIDphZGQKZW5k
#---OBFUSCATED-SECTION-END

package "jenkins"

service "jenkins" do
  supports [:stop, :start, :restart]
  action [:start, :enable]
end
```

Comment: A suggestion from a colleague of mine makes an interesting route to explore: 
If we are trying to provide an immutable 'base-recipe' that people can inherit from - then maybe we can use the SHA-1 key for the git base class to ensure that we keep those sections. Haven't thought through all the details yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a design whereby the file begins with a signed section, describing the signed entities that will be found throughout the file. Your parsing code would then need to check that each entity is present as described and hasn't been deleted.

To prevent replay attacks, you would need to include a time stamp into each signature, and recompute the signatures across the entire file each time you make a change to any of the signed sections. Therefore, a file is only valid if:

- The signed entities described in the "header" are present in the file.
- Each signature verifies and contains an identical time stamp.
- *Optional*: The signature time stamp matches (within an acceptable delta) the file time stamp?

The remaining risk is that someone replaces the entire file with a previous revision (i.e. to effectively delete a new section they don't like). I'm not sure how you can defend against that, except perhaps by examining the file time stamp as suggested above.

*NB. My answer makes assumptions about what you can achieve when creating and parsing the file. I've possibly misunderstood the constraints of your environment (I'm not familiar with git), if so please disregard me!*

Comment: Duncan - thanks for the answer. That's basically the strategy that I was thinking of.  Currently I'm trying a couple of different scenarios in real world testing to see what "takes" operationally etc. will post here with updates on my experiences.